# Verb phrases and suddenly a word usage

Tags: word-usage

I made a question from [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/opinion/sunday/brit-marling-women-movies.html) beforehand.

There is one more question.

> There are centuries of trial and error inside the “hero’s journey,” in which a young man is called to adventure, challenged by trials, faces a climactic battle and emerges victorious, changed and a hero.

At the end of the sentence, there is "changed and a hero," while verb phrases were all listed before that.

It is okay to interpret this as follows?

a young man is called to adventure, challenged by trials, faces a climactic battle and emerges victorious, "is" changed and "becomes" a hero.

Comment: Some people would include an "Oxford comma" after ***changed*** in your cited context, but I'm not sure if that's relevant to your problem. Note that the "problem" is definitely on your side - the actual text as quoted is perfectly okay, with or without that comma.

Comment: Well. It's okay to *interpret* it that way for *yourself*. It is not okay to *reword* it that way for *others*.

Answer (score 1):

This complex and strangely constructed sentence might be understood more easily if set out as follows:

*There are centuries of trial and error inside the “hero’s journey,” in which a young man:*

- is:

  - called to adventure,
  - challenged by trials,
- faces a climactic battle, and
- emerges:

  - victorious,
  - changed, and
  - a hero.

Comment: Note that this is ungrammatical, as it contains _a young man is faces ... and emerges_. The (first) colon needs to come after _man_, and the first two principal bullet points need _is_. Some might object to nested colons.

Comment: I'd separate "faces" and "a climactic battle" (place it on the next line), and I'd move the "and"s to before the last items ("emerges" and "a hero"). "is" 2 items, "faces" 1 item, "emerges" 3 items.

Comment: Is "emerges victorious, changed and a hero" grammatically right or wrong? I didn't see the "emerge + adjectives or nouns" structure in a dictionary. If that is alright, I can make sense of Orbital Aussie's answer.